# GoogleサイトのHTML埋め込みコードを縦・横幅いっぱいに表示する方法

Tags: html

GoogleサイトのHTML埋め込みコードを使用し、iFrameでGoogle Apps Scriptを呼び出し、表示しております。
しかし、スマホで動作確認したところ、どうやら縦幅はGoogleサイトの幅に依存するらしく、スマホとPCで見える縦幅が異なります。

スマホ・PC関係なく、画面幅いっぱいまでiFrameの内容を表示することは可能なのでしょうか？

お手数ですが、ご教授いただきますようお願いいたします。

なお、埋め込んでいるHTML文としては下記になります。

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
          #wrapper {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
          }
          #wrapper:before {
            content:"";
            display: block;
            height: 100%;
          }
          #content {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
          }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <iframe id="content" src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/[id]/exec" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: iFrame自体は縦幅いっぱい表示されていて、`https://script.google.com/macros/s/[id]/exec`を縦幅いっぱい表示したいということですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
iFrame自体も画面いっぱい表示されていない状態です。
Googleサイト側のHTML埋め込みで上記コードを埋め込んでいるのですが、そのHTML埋め込み分の枠でしか表示されない状況です。

Googleサイトの設定上、ある程度縦幅を持たせておき、PCで見るとちょうど画面いっぱい（スクロール不要）になる状態で、スマホから参照すると、スマホの半分くらいまでしか表示されませんでした。